# what is the best way to group your nodes so that you can make faster queries based on location (neo4j)

Tags: database, neo4j, geolocation, location, geospatial

I am new to Neo4j. I want to find out what is the best way to group your nodes so that you can make faster queries based on location using Neo4j.

I will have a lot of users in the database. I will be making queries to return the top 10 users closest to a particular user/location. When making the query, I want to narrow down the search before working out the distances between the users and then ranking them based on who is the closest.

I need advice on the best approach using Neo4j. I can think of two ways to group them but I am not sure if it's feasible or how to execute them yet.

1. Divide the world up into grids, give each grid a cell id and create a node for each id. Make a direct relationship between the users and the cell id.
2. Create a node for each city or town. All users living in that town or city will have a direct relationship. But if I do that how should I group a user that shares two borders?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Luckily we got you covered.

Neo4j has built in spatial indexes, that you can declare on your `location` property, which needs to be a `point({latitude, longitude})`

Then you can use the `point.distance` function to find nodes that are close to a starting point, e.g. passed in from the outside as a location or from a (set of) start node(s).

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/spatial/#functions-distance

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/indexes/#administration-indexes-spatial-distance-searches-single-property-index

i.e.

```
WITH point({latitude:$latitude, longitude:$longitude}) as poi
MATCH (n:Node)
// will use the index
WHERE point.distance(n.location, poi) < 1000
RETURN n 
ORDER BY point.distance(n.location, poi) ASC LIMIT 10
```